# Eclipse launch config fails for classes in second source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

I create the simplest possible modular project in Eclipse 4.21.0 (see below), with two source folders and one package. Both `main` methods just print "Hello".

- If I right-click on `Main1` and *Run as Java Application*, it's all fine.
- If I right-click on `Main2` and do the same, I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class p1.Main2
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: p1.Main2
```

If I check the two run configurations this generated (`Main1` and `Main2`), they are (superficially) *identical*, except for the name of the Main class. If I go into the `Main1` launch configuration and change the main class to `Main2`, now it works. So Eclipse generated a valid launch config for the top source folder, and a broken one for the second source folder.

**Why is this, and how can I generate valid launch configs for other source folders?**

[image]

##### Details

- I'm aware that this is not an issue for non-modular projects, but I'm interested in solving the case for modular projects.
- This happens even when I delete/refresh the launch config before launching, and independently of the order I run `Main1` and `Main2`.
- This happens whether I have a single output folder or one per source folder.

Comment: Does this also occur in the current Eclipse version instead of the outdated one you have? Does it also happen when you deleted the run configuration? Do you have the same output folder for both source folders?

Comment: Thx. I guess the command line (see _Show Command Line_ button in the launch configurations) is not correctly generated for those classes in the source folder not containing the `module-info.java` when a different source folder contains the the `module-info.java` file. Please make sure it has been reported to Eclipse, best with a patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a **known bug** reported on 2020-11-23 for version 4.17: [Cannot launch class if module-info.java is in additional source directory](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569073).

##### Workaround

As indicated in the original bug report, attempting to modify the *broken* configuration does not solve the problem:

> If I edit the launch configuration  (even if I just change the name) I get the following error instead on launching: `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer...`

However, it is possible to create a valid configuration for the *main* source folder (where `module-info.java` is located), and modify *that* configuration to use a main class from the *additional* source folder, which will run fine.

Comment: Good catch. Do you like provide a patch? If yes, do you need help to do so?